# How can I highlight table cells that have been edited and those that are updated as a result?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new in twitter-bootstrap, and I would like to see the posibilites of it.

The idea is: from a cell of a table which I change a value using x-editable, after accepting value, I set it in other cells.

I was thinking to put some effect using bootstrap, but my imagination is off now and I thougt somebody could help me

What I was thinking it is set some color in the cell which was changed from the cell value setted.

I can se images for the reputation if not I would love to be more explicit. I hope you understand what I need with my english words.

Which is the best case for this process using twitter-bootstrap?

I hope you understand my english

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a bit difficult to understand and is also too broad for our format. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: maybe add some images to better describe what you are trying to do? I Cant fully understand it still

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't do that type of thing. You'd need to write some simple jQuery to highlight modified cells. Where Bootstrap comes in is that it provides typography classes to quickly add color, etc. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-colors

Comment: bob did you read question? I dont havce reputation

Comment: at the moment ishewood I was changing the background color using jqueriy, Atr the moment I was thinking something like excel where with arrows indeicates you the cells which is comming, But I think it is difficult to do and I need something easy

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's contextual classes on either a table row or an individual table cell to highlight something.

You'll obviously have to set the row/cell to be highlighted yourself using some JavaScript, PHP or whatever you are using on your project.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes

```
<tr class="active">...</tr>
<tr class="success">...</tr>
<tr class="warning">...</tr>
<tr class="danger">...</tr>
<tr class="info">...</tr>
```

```
<tr>
  <td class="active">...</td>
  <td class="success">...</td>
  <td class="warning">...</td>
  <td class="danger">...</td>
  <td class="info">...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I did that but I was thinking with some effect but anyway  I know I am asking it is difficult